# Retrieving AD user using User.Identity.Name in Web App

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, iis, web-applications

I'm attempting to retrieve an AD user for an Intranet web-app based on the name provided by this code:

```
var userName = User.Identity.Name.Split('\\')[1];
```

Which returns DOMAIN\\USER, and slices it so I can grab just 'USER'.

I then pass this into this method:

```
public bool DoesUserExist(string userName)
{
    using (var domainContext = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, Domain))
    {
        using (var foundUser = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(domainContext, IdentityType.SamAccountName, userName))
        {
            return foundUser != null;
        }
    }
}
```

Running this on my dev machine or published live, it always returns false.

However, if I do this:

```
var domainUser = UserPrincipal.Current;
```

It retrieves the user (in this case, myself) correctly, and when I compare the SamAccountName and the name I pass through in the method, they are the same. The issue with using this, is when the site is published live, it only picks up the IIS App Pool login, whereas the User.Identity.Name picks up the account of the user on the site.

I've tried passing over the name untrimmed and that hasn't worked either.

I'm running out of ideas ; does anybody know if I've missed anything here or have any suggestions that could resolve this issue?

Comment: Code looks almost identical to code I have used successfully. Any chance your `Domain` is not correct? Have you tried just using `using (var principalContext = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain))`, which should connect to the default domain?

Comment: @ste-fu This worked! Thank you. Clearly the domain I was giving it was incorrect. Would you like to answer it with that so I can accept it as the answer? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any chance your `Domain` is not correct?

Have you tried just

```
using (var principalContext = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain))
```

This should connect to the default domain

Comment: This worked, thank you. Been given a domain name to work with by a colleague which I pass into the method but must not be the right one ; this resolved the problem!